# Haskell Particle simulation - calculating velocities of particles

Tags: algorithm, haskell, functional-programming, simulation, particle-system

I am working on a particle simulation program using Haskell. For one of the functions I am trying to determine the new velocities of all the particles in the simulation based on the mass and velocities of all the surrounding particles.

The function is of this form:

```
accelerate :: Float -> [Particle] -> [Particle]
```

Particle is a data type that contains the mass, position vector and velocity vector, the 'Float' argument represents the delta time of the respective time step in the simulation

I would like some suggestions on possible functions I can use to traverse the list while calculating the velocities of each of the particles with respect to the other particles in the list.

One possible approach I can think of:

1. assume there is another function 'velocityCalculator' which has the following definition:

   ```
   velocityCalculator :: Particle -> Particle -> (Float,Float)
   ```

This takes two particles and returns the updated velocity vector for the first particle.

2. apply foldl; using the above function as the binary operator, a particle and the list of particles as the arguments, i.e.

   ```
   foldl velocityCalculator particle particleList
   ```
3. iterate through the list of particle, applying foldl to each element and building the new list containing the particles with the updated velocities

I am not sure if this is the most efficient method so any suggestions and improvements are very much appreciated.

**PLEASE NOTE -> as I have said I am only looking for suggestions not an answer!**

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to apply the velocity verlet algorithm or something similar? I mean, do you wan to integrate Newton's equations of motion using some analytical or numerical potential?

Comment: nothing really so specific, I was just looking for possible higher order functions in haskell that could get the job done quicker in applying the velocityCalculator function across the lists

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you are pretty set on using `foldl`.  For example

3. iterate through the list of particle, applying `foldl` to each element and building the new list containing the particles with the updated velocities

doesn't really make sense.  You apply `foldl` to a list to reduce it to a "summary value", according to some binary summarizing function. It doesn't really make sense to apply it to a single particle.

I am answering this question assuming you are having trouble writing the program in the first place -- it's usually best to do this before worrying about efficiency.  Let me know if I have assumed wrong.

I am not sure what rule you want to use to update the velocities, but I assume it's some sort of pairwise force simulation, for example gravity or electromagnetism.  If this is so, here are some hints that will guide you to a solution.

```
type Vector = (Float, Float)

-- Finds the force exerted on one particle by the other.
-- Your code will be simplified if this returns (0,0) when the two
-- particles are the same. 
findForce :: Particle -> Particle -> Vector

-- Find the sum of all forces exerted on the particle
-- by every particle in the list. 
totalForce :: [Particle] -> Particle -> Vector

-- Takes a force and a particle to update, returns the same particle with
-- updated velocity. 
updateVelocity :: Vector -> Particle -> Particle

-- Calculate mutual forces and update all particles' velocities
updateParticles :: [Particle] -> [Particle]
```

Each of these functions will be quite short, one or two lines.  If you need further hints for which higher-order functions to use, pay attention to the type of the function you are trying to write, and note

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]           -- takes a list, returns a list
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]     -- takes a list, returns a list
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a -- takes a list, returns something else
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b -- takes a list, returns something else
```

Answer (score 2):

You might achieve a speed up by a factor of 2 by memoization, if you give every `Particle` a `particle_id :: Int` ID and then define that:

```
forceOf a b | particle_id a > particle_id b = -(forceOf b a)
            | otherwise = (pos a - pos b) *:. charge a * charge b / norm (pos a - pos b) ^ 3
```

where `(*:.) :: Vector -> Double -> Vector` is vector-scalar multiplication so the above is a `1/r^2` force law. Notice that here we memoize `pos a - pos b` and then we also memoize `forceOf a b` for use as `forceOf b a`.

Then you want to use `dvs = [dt * sum (map (forceOf a) particles) / mass a | a <- particles]` to get a list of changes in velocity, then `zipWith (+) (map velocity particles) dvs`

One problem is that this approach doesn't do so well with numerical uncertainty: everything for time $t+1$ is based on things that were true at time $t$. You can start to solve this problem by solving a matrix equation; instead of v<sub>+</sub> = v + dt * **M** v (where v = v(t) and v<sub>+</sub> = v(t + 1)), you can write v<sub>+</sub> = v + dt * **M** v<sub>+</sub>, so that you have v<sub>+</sub> = (**1** − dt * **M**)<sup>-1</sup> v. That can often be more numerically stable. It is potentially even better to mix the two solutions 50/50. v<sub>+</sub> = v + dt * **M** (v + v<sub>+</sub>) / 2.There are lots of options here.